# Python script inside docker creates empty file with CRON

Tags: python, linux, docker, cron

I have a CRON job set like this :

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/path/to/script && sudo -u myuser ./thescript.sh
```

This script builds a docker image running a simple python app dumping on file a test validation report. When I run this script in a terminal everything works fine (the generated file goes in /home/myuser). Unfortunately, when I run the CRON job, the file is created, but empty. It must have something to do with the Root owning the CRON job, but I can't figure out how to get it done

Any clue ?

Comment: If you use `sudo crontab -e` root will own the cron and execute it with those permissions.  --  That said `root` should be able to write to anything, even in the home directory. This seems like an issue with the .sh file ...  Can you post the offending code that creates the file but nothing in it?

Comment: Could there be any path or environment issues? i.e. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)  Do you have passwordless sudo?

Comment: @boethius, you were right, after investigation it has something to do with the python script not recognizing my environment variables and that failed the script. Any clue on how sharing those variables through Cron ?

Comment: Morning - You could try copying the bash settings into the cron file, above your scheduled jobs (might get out of sync over time though)

Answer (score 0):

A `sudo` requires a TTY and cron doesn't run commands with a TTY. You need to run the cron for root user

This can be done using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Then in cron don't use sudo

```
0 0 * * * cd /home/path/to/script && ./thescript.sh
```